# Tabela HTML com colunas fixed top

Tags: html, table, rolamento, posicionamento

Estou tentando criar uma tabela que ao descer a página, a linha de coluna fique fixa no topo.

Até ai tudo bem, no jQuery eu defini no evento scroll que quando as colunas ficassem abaixo do offset, ele trocasse o Position das colunas para `FIXED` e `POSITION TOP 0px`, e funciona, ela se fixa no topo e acompanha a rolagem.

O problema é que ao rolar a página, o elemento `TH` muda de tamanho, ele não acompanha as linhas da tabela.

Tentei forçar a CLASS do elemento `TH` e `TD` sendo o mesmo, afim de pegar o tamanho do mesmo local. Mesmo assim ao descer a página, o elemento perde alguns pixels.

Dentro da classe do `TH` e `TD`, adicionei

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

para que o `padding` não influencie no seu tamanho, e também não funcionou.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Tem como postar um [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Eu chutaria que o ideal não é alterar o estilo do TH — tirar ele do fluxo da página com `position: fixed` corre o risco de alterar o layout da tabela — mas _clonar_ o TH pra dentro de um <div> (com `display: table-row`, talvez?).